# Ensure label belongs to its checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a checkbox and a label for it. Now I want to ensure that the checkbox belongs to its label, like checkbox1 -> label1. How to do it on capybara?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this depending on what exactly you want to verify and what elements you've already found.  To just verify there is a checkbox with a given label associated you can verify that with either of

```
expect(page).to have_field('associated label text', type: 'checkbox')
expect(page).to have_selector(:checkbox, 'associated label text')
```

If you have already found the checkbox element (checkbox1) and just want to verify it has an associated label either of

```
expect(page).to have_selector(:label, 'label text', for: checkbox1) # if you also want to verify the label text
expect(page).to have_selector(:label, for: checkbox1)
```

If you have already found the label and checkbox elements (label1, checkbox1) and want to verify the elements you found are associated

```
expect(label1).to match_selector(:label, for: checkbox1)
```

Comment: Before I read answer I found that is_expected.to have_field(user.name, type: 'checkbox') is my solution and it's sufficient. Accepting your answer anyway.